# como onsultar SQL dinamicamente con una variable?

Tags: php, sql, base-de-datos, mysqli

Antes que nada, me gustaria decir que soy novato.

Estoy haciendo una pagina de futbol en donde aparezcan los partidos de cada division y de cada fecha.
Para eso cree una base de datos con una tabla llamada 'partidos'
la tabla consiste de lo siguiente:

| id | horario | equipoA | golA | golB | equipoB | dia | fecha | division |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sab 15hs | CCL | 1 | 1 | JUVU | 26/5 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | sab 15hs | JUV | 0 | 2 | DEPU | 26/5 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | dom 15hs | SAR | 2 | 2 | CCE | 27/5 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | dom 15hs | UNI | 1 | 1 | IND | 27/5 | 1 | 2 |

Ya tengo realizada la conexion con php a la base de datos y logre que se muestre a traves del siguente codigo:

```
<select id="selectDivision" onchange= "obtenerSeleccion();">
    <option selected value="1">Division A</option>
    <option value="2">Division B</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option>Fecha 1</option>
    <option>Fecha 2</option>
</select>
<table>
    
    <?php
    $sql= "SELECT * FROM `partidos` ;";
    $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
    while ($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>


    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $mostrar['id'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $mostrar['horario'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $mostrar['equipoA'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $mostrar['golA'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $mostrar['golB'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $mostrar['equipoB'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $mostrar['dia'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $mostrar['fecha'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $mostrar['division'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que a traves del value del select, modificar la sentencia sql para organizarlo por division y por fecha
Ej: "SELECT FROM * partidos where division = $VARIBALE OBTENIDA POR EL SELECT

Comment: ¿Qué tienes en `obtenerSeleccion()`? ¿Hay ahí una llamada Ajax o Fetch para mandar los datos al servidor?

Comment: function obtenerSeleccion(){
  var seleccion = document.getElementById("selectDivision").value;

Comment: ¿Sólo eso? En ese bloque deberías implementar Ajax o Fetch para mandar los datos al servidor.

Comment: Me podes brindar algún articulo o video sobre ese tema?

Answer (score 1):

Antonio Sartoni, sigue mi respuesta.
***1 - Ordenación por divisón y fecha***. 
Su tabla tiene que tener el dia = 'AAAA-MM-DD' ej:('2022-05-26)
***2 - La query ordenada por división:***

```js
SELECT  * FROM PARTIDOS ORDER BY DIVISION,FECHA
```

***3 - Hace un cambio en el select de la fecha***

```html
<select id="select_1" name="fecha">
    <option selected value="1"Fecha 1</option>
    <option value="2"Fecha 2</option>
</select>
```

***4 - La seleción de la División y Fecha***
Para obtener la fecha deber crear una variable $fecha.
Para obtener la divison deber crear una variable $division.

```
<?php
   $division = $_POST['divison'])
  $fecha = $_POST['fecha'])

  $sql= "SELECT * FROM PARTIDOS 
  WHERE DIVISION = $DIVISION
  AND FECHA = $FECHA
  ORDER BY DIVISION,FECHA ;";

  $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
  while ($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 ?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda. Lo voy a implementar y comento luego